# Does an inverted protasis mean just plain “if”, or does it mean “even if”?

Tags: differences, pronouns, conditionals, subject-verb-inversion, protasis

When the first part of a conditional’s *if*-clause is inverted and the *if* consequently dropped, is the missing *if* just a plain old “simple *if*”, or is it more of an “even *if*”?   For example, in this sentence the bold part is an inverted conditional:

> He could not believe that, **had the Englishman known how much he was at risk**, he would have hazarded his grandson.

I’m trying to figure out the exact meaning of the missing *if* through the context, but the example sentence consists of just the three pieces with two conjunctions (*if*-clause, *that*-clause) and there is no more, so I became confused as to which of these senses was intended:

1. **If** the Englishman had known how much he (=Englishman) was at risk, he would have hazarded his grandson.
2. **Even if** the Englishman had known how much he (=his grandson) was at risk, he would have hazarded his grandson.

Which of those two possibilities is the right one here, and in general, how is one to make that determination for any given situation like this one?

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/hazard

Comment: [A] [H]ad the Englishman known how much he was at risk, he would not have gone to Antarctica. This is fine in all aspects. //  [B] [H]ad the Englishman known how much he was at risk, he would not have taken his son. Grammatically fine, but unacceptable without context because it is ambiguous. // [C]  [H]ad the Englishman known how much he was at risk, his son would not have been allowed to go. Again, ambiguous without context. //

Comment: [D] [H]ad the Englishman known how much he was at risk, he would not have hazarded his grandson. Ambiguous, but probably the first _he_ refers to the one who was hazarded (the grandson). //  [E1]  [H]ad the Englishman known how much he was at risk, he would not have hazarded his granddaughter.  Unambiguous. //  [E2]  [H]ad the Englishman known how much she was at risk, he would not have hazarded his granddaughter.  Unambiguous.

Comment: The title is asking about the *if*, while the body is asking about the *he* and has nothing at all to do with the *if*. Please clarify what it is you're after.

Comment: What does "to hazard [a person] mean in BrE? Is it something like "to put [a person] in danger"?

Comment: @RegDwigнt He seems to assume that when the meaning of _if_ changes, the antecedent of _he_ changes automatically. Notice that he bolded _Even if_ in the second version. I'm not sure why he thinks this correspondence exists, though.

Answer (score -1):

There really isn't a definite answer here, but my best input is that *even if* is commonly used within a sentence that is somehow connected to a previous statement or idea, and the standalone *if* is used in the case in question where there is no external context.

Examples:

> I am never going to win the lottery. **Even if** I did, I wouldn't know what to do with millions of dollars.

The second sentence plays off of the first sentence, therefore requiring *even if*.

> **If** I won the lottery, I wouldn't know what to do with millions of dollars.

This is standalone, so *even* is not needed.

I guess what I'm saying is *even* is used for association and comparison.